# JDBC DB2 URL with Comma-Separated List of currentFunctionPath

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I feel like this should be extremely simple, and yet for some reason I just cannot find an answer anywhere.

I am setting up a DataSource which does not have a lot of setters for properties that I want to set. As a result, I am using the jdbc URL to pass some of my connection properties into the application.

I need to set a currentFunctionPath with a comma separated list of schemas. Normally, this could be achieved by running the following sql:

```
set path ASCHEMA, ANOTHERSCHEMA, YETANOTHERSCHEMA;
```

But, I need this to be the case for all of my connections in the application, so I want to use the following jdbc URL:

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:55555/FOLDER:currentSchema=ASCHEMA;currentFunctionPath=ASCHEMA,ANOTHERSCHEMA,YETANOTHERSCHEMA;
```

Whenever I do this, however, I receive a URL syntax error, and it appears to always stop reading the line as soon as it gets to the first comma in my comma-separated path list.

I've tried &s, and quotes, and double quotes, etc, but I just can't figure out how to make this work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Note: The reason I need to do this involves calling stored procedures which call other stored procedures which are not fully qualified. I am unable to modify those stored procedures to make them fully qualified.

Error:

```
Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://localhost:55555/FOLDER:currentSchema=ASCHEMA;currentFunctionPath=ASCHEMA. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

Comment: Did you try, `currentFunctionPath="ASCHEMA,ANOTHERSCHEMA,YETANOTHERSCHEMA";`?

Comment: @user2004685 Yes, I sure did. I just tried again. The error I receive is:

`Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://localhost:55555/FOLDER:currentSchema=ASCHEMA;currentFunctionPath="ASCHEMA. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
 at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)`

As you can see the error stops abruptly at the first comma. It does not like commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it turned out, DB2 didn't hate the comma-separated list of currentFunctionPath at all.

In fact, I was passing in the jdbc url from a properties file. When Java pulled the jdbc url from the properties file, it was ending the property at the comma. I tested this by doing a System.out.println(theurl) on the url.

All I had to do was escape the commas with a backslash (\) so that java would actually pull the property properly. Then everything worked as normal.

```
jdbc:db2://localhost:55555/FOLDER:currentSchema=ASCHEMA;currentFunctionPath=ASCHEMA\,ANOTHERSCHEMA\,YETANOTHERSCHEMA;
```

I'm glad to have that solved!